# Why my Regex is only giving me ONE group back?

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-group

Im currenty having issues with a regex that Im creating. The regex has to extract all the groups that says number #### between Hello and Regards. At this moment my regex only extracts one group and I need all the groups inside, at this case I have 2, but there may be more inside.

[Regex Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coslH.png)

I'm using the web page https://regex101.com/

**Flavor**: **PCRE (PHP)**

**Regex**: `Hello\s.*(number\s*[\d]*)\s.*Regards`

**Text**:

```
This is my test text number 25120
Hello my name is testing
I'm 20 years old
Please help me with the regex number 1542
I have been trying to create the regex many times this is my number 5152
Regards
I'm still trying my attempt number 5150
```

**Result**:

My Result is only the group number 5152 but inside is another group number 1542.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please see [why not upload images of code when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Capture groups always hold only the last match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
(?si)(?:\G(?!\A)|\bHello\b)(?:(?!\bHello\b).)*?\K\bnumber\s*\d+(?=.*?\bRegards\b)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V6HALd/2).

**Details**

- `(?si)` - `s` - DOTALL modifier making `.` match any chars, and `i` makes the pattern case insensitive
- `(?:\G(?!\A)|\bHello\b)` - either the end of the previous match (`\G(?!\A)`) or (`|`) a whole word `Hello` (`\bHello\b`)
- `(?:(?!\bHello\b).)*?` - any char, 0 or more times but as few as possible, that does not start a whole word `Hello` char sequence
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards all text matched so far
- `\bnumber` - a whole word `number`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?=.*?\bRegards\b)` - there must be a whole word `Regards` somewhere after any 0+ chars (as few as possible).